# Printing a character based sine-curve is not continuous

Tags: c

I have the following code which should output the character image of a sine curve:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

/**show the image of sine curve*/
main()
{
    double y;
    int m, x;
    for (y = 1; y >= 0; y -= 0.1) {
        m = asin(y) * 10;
        for (x = 1; x < m; x++)
            printf(" ");
        printf("*");
        for (; x < 31 - m; x++)
            printf(" ");
        printf("*\n");
    }
    for (y = 0; y <= 1; y += 0.1) {
        m = 31 + asin(y) * 10;
        for (x = 1; x < m; x++)
            printf(" ");
        printf("*");
        for (; x < 93 - m; x++)
            printf(" ");
        printf("*\n");
    }
}
```

This is the output it generates:

```
              * *
          *         *
        *             *
      *                 *
     *                   *
    *                     *
   *                       *
  *                         *
 *                           *
*                             *
*                              *
                              *                               *
                               *                             *
                                *                           *
                                 *                         *
                                  *                       *
                                   *                     *
                                    *                   *
                                     *                 *
                                       *             *
                                         *         *
                                             * *
```

As you can see, my code's result is not continuous. I want to know where my code is incorrect. And on the other hand, I would appreciate it if someone could give me a better solution.

Comment: @Bart: The OP wants to draw a sine curve, which should be continuous. The code draws a sine curve with a displacement in the bottom half.

Comment: @Vogel612: The objects are assigned before they are used.

Comment: @Bart: The question does say that. The comment in the code says “show the image of the sine curve” and text in the question says “My code’s result is not continuous.” It is completely clear what the desired result is and what incorrect result is obtained.

Comment: @EricPostpischil not quite. for example i would have never guessed (or known/seen) that the bottom half is displaced...

Comment: @zongzhengli formatting the code is fine. Editing it is not. You removed some essential characters there.

Comment: sorry, friends,I am a green hand,and my english needs to be improved.

my aim is to draw a sine curve

Comment: escape characters "\n"

Comment: @Bart Yes, sorry about that. I ran it through a bugged code formatter.

Comment: I think downvotes should be removed from this question.

Comment: Image is also compressed for the most part 2 places to left for all but the first asterisk.  Detailed comments in answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code for the top half of the sine wave prints *m* spaces, an asterisk, then a number of spaces *x*, then an asterisk. The number *x* is calculated such that there would be *m* spaces after the second asterisk to reach a total of 31 spaces printed. The code for the bottom half allots 31 spaces to continue the sine wave after the distance covered by the top half. This fails to account for the fact that the top half is printed in a field of 33 characters: 31 spaces and two asterisks. The second loop should print two more spaces at the beginning of each line.

Notes:

Presumably 31 was chosen to scale the wave so that half a wavelength is 10 π. In this case, the depiction would be more accurate if the top were adjusted to print two asterisks in a field of 31 characters instead of 33.

More accurate yet would be to account for fractional character spaces and print the asterisks in the nearest space.

Additionally, it is only happenstance that the loop counters work out as desired, since floating-point arithmetic is used without regard for the rounding errors that occur. With different values, the loops might have an iteration count off by one from what is desired. It would be preferable to reformulate the code to use a loop counter with integer values (although possibly still floating-point type).

Answer (score 1):

The problem that your curve is not continuous is solved by adding two spaces in the `printf("*")` statement before `*` in the second part (bottom half).

```
   for(y=0;y<=1;y+=0.1){
            m=31+asin(y)*10;
            for(x=1;x<m;x++) printf(" ");
            printf("  *");
            for(;x<93-m;x++) printf(" ");
            printf(" *\n");
    }
```

It will print a continuous `sine` curve.
**Output**:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Its really only the first half of the Sine that is causing the discontinuity.  The entire first half is two spaces to the left.  The real fix is to adjust the algorithm for these deficiencies so each quadrant starts at the correct position (Eric P. has described it well).  The cheap fix however, is to shift everything right, starting by adjusting the first value of `m` (x-position) to appear to the right, then using spaces thereafter to propagate the fix through the entire waveform.

The continuity, *and shift* are corrected in this code, with comments showing where corrections are made:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
/**show the image of sine curve*/
main(){
    double y;
    int m,x;
    for(y=1;y>=0;y-=0.1)
    {
        m=(asin(y)*10) +1;//"+1" to shift right 1
        for(x=1;x<m;x++)  //to get first 11
        {                 //asterisks in sync. spaces used thereafter
            printf(" ");
        }
        printf("*");
        for(;x<32-m;x++) 
        {
            printf(" ");
        }
        printf(" *\n"); //" "1 additional space to shift image right
    }
    for(y=0;y<=1;y+=0.1)
    {
            m=31+asin(y)*10;
            for(x=1;x<m;x++) 
            {
                printf(" ");
            }
            printf("   *"); //2 additional spaces to shift image right
            for(;x<93-m;x++) 
            {
                printf(" ");
            }
            printf("*\n");
    }
    getchar();
}
```

***Here is an image of shifted, continuous output:  ***

[image]